# rsync does not exclude extension when executed as a cron job

Tags: ubuntu, cron, rsync

I'm trying to use rsync to backup all files and directories on my server, not really everything, I want to exclude a few things so I do:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -aAXh  --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /* /mnt/backupdirectory
```

It works well and does exactly what it is supposed to do until I put it in a cron job to do it everyday.

```
30 23 * * * ~/scripts/backup_system.sh > ~/scripts/logs/backup_system.log 2>&1
```

When executed as a cron job, it doesn't exclude all the directories it is supposed to exclude. I don't understand why. Couldn't someone explain to me why?

I don't think it matters much but the system in use is Ubuntu Server 14.04.

---

The problem was pointed out in the answer below. The use of braces in cron is not valid and I had to replace the previous command by:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -aAXh --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/run/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/media/* --exclude=/lost+found /* /mnt/backupdirectory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check three things:

1. What is the error in the mail from cron?
2. Do not use tilde expansion. Use full path names.
3. Does your script set a `PATH`? Because cronjobs do not inherit any `PATH`.

The last point is responsible for 99% of all cron surprises.
Use something like

```
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)
```

at the beginning of your script. To test it on the command line, run it with an empty environment, e.g.

```
/usr/bin/env -i /path/to/script.sh
```

As long as that doesn't work, the cronjob won't.

Comment: 1. I don't know if there is such thing as a mail from cron, in the log, there are many permission denied errors in directories I don't want to backup. There is another error I also got when executing the command manually so I think it's not relevant.     
    
2. tilde was used only here, there are no tildes in my crontab.    
     
3. Other cron jobs work fine, in the script I call from cron, I also make an archive out of the rsync output and the archiving job works fine. From what I see, the cron job is fine but the rsync command is not executed correctly. I will check the PATH issue.

Comment: 3. tested, with a dummy script, the cron job works fine

Comment: @Nicolas 1) Cron mails all output on stdout or stderr to the user associated with the crontab. If your script produces output, it's in that user's mail. 2) Does your non-dummy script set the `PATH`? If it doesn't, that is a big problem. 3) The '{x,y,z}' syntax is non-standard shell syntax. Cronjobs are executed by `/bin/sh` (which might be a bash in disguise, but it may also be operating in POSIXLY_CORRECT mode and not recognize the brace expansion syntax.)

Comment: Great catch! The use of braces was the reason it didn't work as expected. Thank you very much for your help, I learnt something today.

Answer (score 4):

Because crontab use sh as default shell , it not support brace expansion
so the `--exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"}` not work

you can add

> SHELL=/bin/bash

above your crontab job.

for example

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
1 1 * * * cp /test/{*txt,*sh} /tmp/
```

Comment: The brackets were the problem for me (OS: "Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS").  Switching to separate --exclude 'dirA' --exclude 'dirB' did the trick.